# Azure Logic Apps: Random Workflow Disconnection with 'WorkflowNotFound' Error

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm facing an issue with Azure Logic Apps where the connection between workflows randomly disconnects after about an hour. I receive the following error message: "WorkflowNotFound. The workflow 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' could not be found."

All the workflows I'm working with are connected using the GUI by selecting the ones that Azure finds automatically.

I'm not sure how to address this problem, as all the workflows I'm working with are stateful since the stateless ones won't even start for me.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem or knows how to fix it?

I've tried reconnecting the workflows, working in other browsers, checked if there were any outages with azure and waited to see if it fixes itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons for getting workflow not found error in standard logic app. Below are possible reasons,

- Standard logic app will run or work properly if all the configurations done properly. For example, storage connection, run time version etc.
  [image]
- Check whether standard logic app is succesfully running or not. You can test this by clicking browse option in overview. If it does not open then there is issue in logic app itself and need to fix that.
  [image]
- Check if all the workflows and each action input and output. Sometimes workflow will save successfully but it will give problems when input or output expressions are not written properly.
- There are some ways to find out cause for the issue. Enable application insights on logic app and check if you can find error information.
  [image]
- One of the alternative way is using Diagnose and solve problems. This will help in identifying availability, performance , Runs, triggers etc. information related to logic app.
  [image]
- Another way is create a new workflow and see if the issue persists with new logic app also. If it is the case, I would suggest you to raise request with Microsoft support.
- Try to restart standard logic app and see it may resolve your issue.

Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/636152/failed-to-start-a-logic-app-run-the-workflow-workf)

Comment: thanks when I am at the office I will give you a update and see if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've resolved the issue, but not by modifying the workflows. It seems there is some ongoing issue related to Azure's infrastructure.

Based on my deduction, it appears that there are multiple versions of Logic Apps depending on the location where they are created, either within or outside the resource group. I'm unsure why I encountered different Logic App versions based on location, but there is one version called "Logic App" that contains workflows, and another version called "Logic app" that does not.

The Logic App version without workflows remains connected, but the one with workflows still doesn't stay connected even after applying the tips mentioned earlier in this thread.

So, to summarize, my suggestion to Microsoft is to address the naming inconsistency and clarify the behavior of the Logic App versions with and without workflows.